# Increase height on angular material 2 moves placeholder

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I am trying to increase the size of material 2 input control by setting the height property of the input from css

```
<input mdInput placeholder="Favorite food" class="search-grid-input">

.search-grid-input {
    height:30px!important;
}
```

and I get the following on the right part of the image below:

[image]

Comment: Height is increased, So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry. If you see the screenshot the placeholder goes on top instead of staying on center of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version 1:**
You should increase the size of font of input filed, that will cover the area automatically.

```
md-input-container {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

**Version 2:**
You should use text area.

**Version 3:**
Specify placeholder space from top:

```
.mat-input-placeholder-wrapper {
  top: 10px;
}
```

Note: I have copied classes names while using beta.8 version.

Comment: Thanks I used Version 1